# MissingMemberException was unhandled on ultrawebgrid asp.net

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

Am trying to access the childs of my ultrawebgrid but am not sure what code is the correct one for asp.net. I know in vb.net i used the same code and it was fine. I get the error : `MissingMemberException was unhandled.Public member 'getChildRow' on type 'GroupByRow' not found`. Anyone has any ideas?

Here is my code

```
Protected Sub UltraWebGrid1_InitializeLayout(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UltraWebGrid1.Click
        Dim rowSelected As UltraWebGrid
        Dim orderID As Integer
        Dim finalPriceData As OracleDataReader

        For Each rG1 In UltraWebGrid1.Rows
            For Each rL1 In rG1.getChildRow
                For Each rowSelected In UltraWebGrid1.DisplayLayout.SelectedRows
                    orderID = rowSelected.Rows.FromKey("ORDERID").ToString
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you get the exception because there is no such method/property named `getChildRow` in the control's rows. Based on my limited knowledge of VB.NET and `UltraWebGrid`, you may want to try out following things:

1. Change `getChildRow` to `getChildRow()` - this is assuming that earlier syntax is searching from property while later would search for method.
2. A row of type `GroupByRow` may not have `getChildRow` member and so you may want to skip that kind of row - For Example
   `If TypeOf(rG1) IS NOT GroupByRow Then

   For Each rL1 In rG1.getChildRow`
3. Lastly, from [documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2011.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v11.1~Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.UltraGridRow.html), it appears that grid contains rows of type `UltraGridRow` and probable code for iterating child rows may go something like

-

```
For Each rG1 In UltraWebGrid1.Rows
   If rG1.HasChildRows Then
      For Each rL1 In rG1.Rows
         ...
      Next
   End If
Next
```

Comment: You were right. I used ur last code and it works fine now. THank you very much